# How do you wait until multiple onReady/services are ready until executing method

Tags: android

I have a onReady (to wait for google maps to be ready) and an onConnected (to wait for the Google Api Client/Service to be connected). I want to run some code after both of those services are ready/connected (wait for the google map to be ready so I can display the user's last location on the map. The last location needs to be gotten from the Google Api Client). I am unsure how to do this in Java/Android and I am just starting out.

Thanks!